# servlet container managed bean

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Lately I realized that Servlets are container managed beans. Since Tomcat or any container as such will create these and use them. I have the following questions:

1. For a given Servlet, is there only one servlet object created? Since I believe one is enough.
2. The request object is a frequently created object; does the container maintain it in some sort of pool, if so how can I change the value?